# Is replication on by default on MySQL 8.0.30 ? How to stop it?

Tags: mysql, replication, configuration, php, phpmyadmin

I am running `MySQL 8.0.30` on `Rocky Linux 9`.

While importing some ~100GB sql files, I noticed the `/var/lib/mysql` is filled with `binlog.000123` files, over 100GB.

I assume these are created because server is somehow configured to be part of replication, but I don't remember enabling anything related to this.

But in `PHP MyAdmin 5.2.0-1.el9` under replication I see:

```
Primary replication
This server is configured as primary in a replication process.
```

and

```
Show connected replicas
Server ID   Host
[empty]
```

- So this server is configured to be part of a replication ?
- Is that enabled by default in MySQL 8.0.30 ?
- How do I safely stop replication in this case ?

**Might be relevant:** I have this setup on 4 servers on same local network and they connect to one another by PHP mysqli code/queries, but I didn't use/configure any replication function in mysql, just using normal `mysqli_select_db(s1/s2/etc)` in php code (between the 4 servers) like connecting to an external db.
And while setting them up, I mirrored the HDDs from one server to another, is that a problem because the MySQL config for all servers have exact same `server id` and `server uuid` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain backup techniques use the binlog, too.

To turn off the generation of binlogs in `MySql 8.0` add this to the config file and restart:

```
[mysqld]
skip-log-bin
```

I don't think it will remove the files; do (as mysql's root):

```
 PURGE BINARY LOGS;
```

Comment: Will it increase the risk of broken tables in case of power failure ? IF so, I have to leave it on.

Comment: Can you tell me what to tune so it runs faster but not risk having broken tables ? If it simply fails to update/insert some data on power failure, that is not a problem at all.

Comment: "broken tables"?  That only happened in MyISAM; you are using InnoDB with 8.0.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I thought maybe I didn't get broken tables for a year because I use SSDs with "Power Loss Protection" :))